# What do I need to know to properly kasher utensils in boiling water?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

If someone wants to kasher their utensils using a pot of boiling water, what do they need to know to do it correctly?

Among other issues, consider:

Are there issues with how long items need to be in the water?

How much water does there need to be?

Can some items not be kashered this way?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no minimum amount of time for the items to be in the water.
2. There should be 60 times the volume of the utensils.
3. Any material than can be kashered can be kashered this way, however, this will not work for frying pans or grills, which became non-kosher over the fire.

Furthermore, the first rule of kashering utensils is to wait 24 hours after they became non-kosher. This is because waiting 24 hours allows the "flavor" of the non-kosher food to become not tasty. This makes my rule No. 2 less important. (It is still nice, but not essential under normal circumstances.)

If, however, you for some reason cannot wait, you must make sure that there are 60 times the volume of the utensil, and/or you could use a fairly large amount of powerful soap, but in such a case the specifics become very important and you should ask the specific question to someone who can understand the situation.

Comment: "Among other issues" was meant to say "Don't just answer the following three questions, but consider them as examples."  And sources would be nice.

Comment: There kinda is a minimum for the time. However long you guesstimate it takes for the blios to cook out.

Comment: You can use it for a grill to kasher from Hetera IINM.

Comment: User6591 - although it is difficult to prove the non-existence of a concept, I will say that such an idea is not present anywhere in Shas or Posekim. Unless you can bring a proof to such a concept, I will defend it's non-existence.